# BrowserManager in chrome not changing title of browser's tab

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, browser

i'm using BrowserManager.setTitle to try to change the browser's tab title but it's not affecting not chrome and not firefox. any workaround known?

Comment: By all means do not post the code you used to try to get it to work. We probably wouldn't want to see it anyway. After all it is broken.

Comment: @The_asMan, please leave the snark out and just say "show some code!" :P

Comment: As for BrowserManager, I've had inconsistent behavior from it.  Is there a reason you're using it instead of say a Javascript call of sorts?

Answer (score 0):

After some digging around, I found the answer in another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352940/can-someone-help-me-with-dynamic-page-titles-in-actionscript-3-please) but they're using Javascript to do the dirty work (which I would recommend).